# Match values of two different arrays & Rebuild

Tags: php, arrays

I need to match the values of two different arrays. If `position` from `array_1` is in `array_2` then assign the position & description to a new array. If the `position` from `array_1` is not in `array_2` then assign the `position` with an empty description to the new array.

My PHP code (below) isn't working because of the second `foreach`. It's overwriting the new array (`position_array`). It's only writing the last description.

array_1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 6
    [5] => 12
)
```

array_2:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [position] => 2
            [description] => Text 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [position] => 4
            [description] => Text 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [position] => 6
            [description] => Text 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [position] => 12
            [description] => Text 4
        )
)
```

PHP:

```
print_r($_POST['position']);
print_r($_POST['position_desc']);

$position=$_POST['position'];
# Check if there was POST data sent.
if(isset($_POST['position_desc']))
{
    # Create an empty array.
    $position_array=array();
    # Loop through the user's positions.
    foreach($position as $position_key=>$position_value)
    {
        foreach($_POST['position_desc'] as $desc_key=>$position_desc)
        {
            echo $position_value.' -> '.$position_desc['position'].' - ';
            if($position_value==$position_desc['position'])
            {
                echo 'MATCH - Assign Desc<br>';
                # Assign the position and description to the array.
                $position_array[$position_key]=array('position'=>$position_value, 'description'=>$position_desc['description']);
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc<br>';
                # Assign the position and description to the array.
                $position_array[$position_key]=array('position'=>$position_value, 'description'=>'');
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($position_array);
    exit;
```

Result:

```
1 -> 2 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
1 -> 4 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
1 -> 6 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
1 -> 12 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
2 -> 2 - MATCH - Assign Desc
2 -> 4 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
2 -> 6 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
2 -> 12 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
3 -> 2 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
3 -> 4 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
3 -> 6 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
3 -> 12 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
4 -> 2 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
4 -> 4 - MATCH - Assign Desc
4 -> 6 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
4 -> 12 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
6 -> 2 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
6 -> 4 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
6 -> 6 - MATCH - Assign Desc
6 -> 12 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
12 -> 2 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
12 -> 4 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
12 -> 6 - NO MATCH - Assign empty Desc
12 -> 12 - MATCH - Assign Desc

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [position] => 1
            [description] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [position] => 2
            [description] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [position] => 3
            [description] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [position] => 4
            [description] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [position] => 6
            [description] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [position] => 12
            [description] => Text 4
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `break` to end the second foreach and avoid overwriting.

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array1 as $position) {
    $temp = array();
    foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
        $temp = array(
            'position' => $position,
            'description' => ""
        );
        if ($value['position'] == $position) {
            $temp['description'] = $value['description'];
            unset($array2[$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
    $newArray[] = $temp;
}
```

Comment: Of course, unset() it and break. Wow. Thanks so much!